# Trying to figure out 'bundle install' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create my first app in rail but when I try the rails server command I get the following message "Could not find gem 'sdoc (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

how to run bundle install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run it on bash (I.e. terminal) just type `bundle install`
It will bring what's missing in your gem file and install it for you.

Comment: @OneWingedAng3l please  consider accepting this as an answer (Mark with V)

Answer (score 0):

just hit `bundle install` in your terminal man (cd to your project directory)...